# using JSON object in different function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript which parse the server data and stores it in a variable. I can use that variable only in one function but not in multiple functions, please find the javascript code below.

```js
function serverData(command, param) {
    console.log('command is ' + command + ' param is ' + param);
    if (!command) {
        console.log('Command not recieved, No call to Server');
        return;
    }
    var url = 'ProgramSetting.cgi?command=' + command;
    if (param) {
        url += '&' + param;
    }
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            responseHandler(command, data);
        }
    };
}

function responseHandler(command, jsonData) {
    if (!jsonData) {
        console.log('Json from server not defined!!!');
        return;
    }

    switch (command) {
        case 'set':
            if (jsonData.result == 'success') {
                document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'INFO: Committed successfully!';
            } else {
                if (jsonData.options && jsonData.options.length > 0) {
                    var failedOptions = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.options.length; i++) {
                        failedOptions += ' ' + jsonData.options[i];
                    }
                    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
                        'ERROR: Failed to commit following option(s)-' + failedOptions;
                } else {
                    console.log('Failed to Commit');
                    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'ERROR: Failed to Commit';
                }
                initialPageLoad();
                document.getElementById('info').style.color = 'red';
            }
            break;

        case 'get':
            console.log('jsonData.POLICY is ' + jsonData.POLICY);
            if (jsonData.POLICY == 'gehc') {
                document.getElementById('list1').checked = true;
                gehc();
            } else if (jsonData.POLICY == 'strict') {
                document.getElementById('list2').checked = true;
                strictgehc();
            } else if (jsonData.POLICY == 'custom') {
                document.getElementById('list3').checked = true;
                custom(jsonData);
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log("we don't support this");
    }
}

function custom(jsonData) {
    console.log('Custom called');
    console.log('jsonData.MINLEN_RANGE is ' + jsonData.MINLEN_RANGE);
    document.getElementById('Minlen_text').value = jsonData.MINLEN_RANGE;
    document.getElementById('Minlen_text').disabled = false;
    console.log('jsonData.EXPIRY is ' + jsonData.EXPIRY);
    document.getElementById('Expiry_text').value = jsonData.EXPIRY;
    document.getElementById('Expiry_text').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false;
}

function initialPageLoad() {
    console.log('Retrieving data from Server calling get');
    serverData('get');
}
```

In the above script I am able to use `jsonData` in `responseHandler()` function but cannot use in``custom()` function.

Comment: Can you provide some runnable version of fiddle to show your issue

Comment: My first guess would be that the responseHandler method should be async.A running version of this would be nice

Comment: Nothing about the code you're showing suggests your call to `custom(jsonData)` inside `responseHandler` won't work in principle. So simplify your code, and show that it doesn't. Also, on an important technical note, JSON is a string, and _only_ a string. By definition, it cannot be anything else, and needs to be parsed to be usable. Once you parse it, it becomes normal JS data structures, and is no longer JSON. You correctly call it `data` in your XHR code, don't call it `jsonData` in your two functions: it's _still_ `data`, not "json".

Comment: My question is very simple that my responseHandler(command, jsonData) function is working perfectly but my custom(jsonData) function is not working. and the error I am getting is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MINLEN_RANGE' of undefined"